# Hover em dois elementos ao mesmo tempo

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu possuo uma div e dentro dela um `<a>` consigo dar hover na div, mas a cor da ancora não muda.

Estrutura HTML:

```
<div class="TamanhoECorTabs ThemeGrid_Width6">
  <a id="ancora" tabindex="14" href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Estrutura CSS:

```css
.TamanhoECorTabs:hover, .TamanhoECorTabs a:hover{
  background-color: #428bca !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  border:none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #428bca !important;
}
```

Preciso que quando passar o mouse pela div, mude a cor da ancora, sem precisar passar o mouse sobre a ancora para que o hover funcione.

Outra coisa que está acontecendo é que mesmo a Home estando ativa o hover aparece. Como faço para tirar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo básico:

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.TamanhoECorTabs:hover, .TamanhoECorTabs a:hover{
    background-color: #428bca !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border:none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #428bca !important;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/AaM2b/)

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente. Gostaria de saber se você sabe como como tirar o efeito hover quando a div esta selecionada, como estive com o .active

Comment: @ThiagoAlex editei a resposta, veja se funciona

Comment: @DouglasBernardino Não funcionou isso, a div está selecionada mas toda vez que passo o mouse em cima ela ativa o hover.

Comment: @ThiagoAlex se ta falando assim: quando você clica no Home ele carrega a página home.html, ai você clica em Noticia ele carrega a página noticia.html e ai quem está selecionado não pode ter o efeito hover, outra coisa se usa programação, alguma linguagem?

Comment: @ThiagoAlex e ai posso te ajudar mais? se viu minha último questionamento?

Comment: @HarryPotter exatamente isso. A Div selecionada é a Home e a página carregada é a home.html, essa por sua vez não não pode receber o hover da outra div que não está carregada ou selecionada. E eu estou mexendo no `OutSystems` por enquanto não posso usar javascript ou qualquer outra linguagem. Só tenho acesso ao css.

Comment: Tem linguagem de programação?

Comment: Porque é assim que a gente faz: quando um página é carregada eu consigo pegar qual endereço foi executado e mudar em tempo de execução a CSS do objeto selecionado, até dá pra tirar o link desse item deixando um div com cor somente. Mas se você não pode usar nem Javascript nem outra linguagem eu não conheço outra forma, peço desculpas.

Comment: Eu estava desconfiando disso já, eu usaria Javascript pra fazer isso se fosse em uma IDE diferente dessa que estou usando. Mas Muito obrigado @HarryPotter

Answer (score 1):

É só colocar esse display block:

```
a{
   display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aap2H/

Answer (score 1):

Para deixar selecionado e sem o evento de hover:

**CSS:**

```
.TamanhoECorTabs:focus, .TamanhoECorTabs a:focus{
    background-color: #428bca !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    border:none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #428bca !important;
    cursor:default;
}
```

**Exemplo:**
http://fiddle.jshell.net/3U5Kn/6/

Caso não queria que ele retorne mais valores no efeito de click, ai terá que fazer uma verificação em seu código, pois quando recarregar a página, você pode estar na página "Home" mas não vai estar com "home" selecionado no menu. Mande seu código para que resolvemos este problema!